# Searching exact variable in a text file using python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to search exact variable in a file but not able to do so. I.e. if I search for 'akash' in a file then all lines that contain akash is returned, even if they contain only 'akashdeep' and not exact 'akash'.

```
__author__ = 'root'
def userinGroups(userName):
   with open('/etc/group','r') as data:
       associatedGroups=[]
       for line in data:
        if userName in line:
           associatedGroups.append(line.split(':')[0])
   return associatedGroups

print userinGroups('akash')
```

This function must only return lines containing 'akash' and not those containing 'akashdeep'.
I tried using `re` module but can not find any example where a variable has been searched.
I also tried:

```
for 'akash' in line.split(':')
```

But in this scenario if a line contains multiple group entries then this fails.

Comment: So, you want `if userName+':' in line:`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, that will fail for names at the end of the line

Comment: @Padraic `if any(userName+n in line for n in (':','\n')):`?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, there are also commas for multiple user per group, a regex is actually the best solution here

Answer (score 0):

Using regex you can use re.search:

```
def userinGroups(userName):
    r = re.compile(r'\b{0}\b'.format(userName))
    with open('/etc/group', 'r') as data:
        return [line.split(":", 1)[0] for line in data if r.search(line)]
```

Or use subprocess to run the groups command:

```
from subprocess import check_output
def userinGroups(userName):
    return check_output(["groups",userName]).split(":",1)[1].split()
```

Comment: i tried this but this solution fails if  there are more users in a group in that case it will be [akash,user2,user3]  here user exists but still result will not be shown consider below line in file  and you are searching for 'akashdeep'
aaronituser:x:512:akashdeep,anamika,parvinder,amit

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have found solution to my problem with  help of all members who responded to this post.Here goes the final solution

```
__author__ = 'root'
import re

def findgroup(line,userName):
    result=re.findall('\\b'+userName+'\\b',line)
    if len(result)>0:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def userinGroups(userName):
   with open('/etc/group','r') as data:
       associatedGroups=[]
       for line in data:
        if findgroup(line,userName):
           associatedGroups.append(line.split(':')[0])
   return associatedGroups



print userinGroups('akas')
```